# Different Problem installing ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

Hello everyone i have a lot of trouble installing ubuntu to my windows 8 pc which is lenovo-G50 series.
        The problem is that at i tried install ubuntu alongside windows 8.But when i inserting my bootable USB the option is not available.It is displaying that **"Ubuntu didn't recognize any operating system"** and is asking for a full format,but i have windows 8 installed.Then after surfing the net for a long time them i understood that my windows 8 os is installed in a different way and also the partition is different.So the option to **"install windows alongside them"** is not available. 
So then again tried to install ubuntu in a different way by partitioning my F drive to 50 gb and created a new free space.Again i inserted my both usb and also Ubuntu cd.But i found the option to **"install windows alongside them"** is not available is missing so i clicked the option **"something else"** to install ubuntu in the free space i created.But i could not find that free space too in that list.I can only see **"/dev/sda"**.

Now i don't know what to do.**Ubuntu is not detecting my os.**I tried to install ubuntu with and without partition, it is neither showing the option **"install windows alongside them"** nor **"My created free partition"**.I am not able to find answer for this problem.Please help me.

In my bios setting i can see that the usb boot is in legacy modes.

Answer (score 0):

When you shrink your main volume (or partition it), try leaving the free space UN-formatted. in windows it should say something like "unallocated space". (you can do this using disk management in windows, just right click and hit `delete volume` on the free partition you want to use).

if that doesn't work, or if you had already done this, try the other way:

format the partition as an NTFS.

Comment: I already  tried the way u told but i still cannot see my free space in the ubuntu installation.